# Refreshing ListView on every few sec

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updating the List UI with Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968911/updating-the-list-ui-with-timer)

I am trying to do something like reminder. At the moment I have a database where every record has a remaining time. I show them as a custom list. I have two lists:

- one for active records from db (depends on time set);
- one for expired records.

I need to refresh the list on every few seconds like 3–5 seconds to check which record is still active. I read about `notifyDataSetChanged();` but I want to refresh it on every 3–5 seconds.
Any simple way to make this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968911/updating-the-list-ui-with-timer

Comment: Create an Adapter and change its data. If you have time read a littel about it. It's not so hard.

Answer (score -1):

Look up Timer in the javadoc. It allows you to set up a task to run every few seconds.